# preventing access in shared hosting

Tags: linux

I set up a small shared hosting that contains some sites. 
For each site, there is a user. I mean, for abcd.com, I created abcd.com user and put htdocs for web hosting.
I have no idea on how to prevent abcd.com from accessing xyzd.com's data. 
I have chmoded by changing 0 to others permission, which makes access defined by Apache 
when I view it with browser.

How can I secure access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use sumod_php, or suexec for apache, to force apache's process to iteract as owner of VirtualHost. I.e.

```
<VirtualHost ...>  
  ... bla-bla-bla ...  
  SuexecUserGroup <user> <group>  
</VirtualHost>
```

More information can be found at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html